# Scheduling a task to be performed at logon (of any user) in vbScript

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

Alright so I have been searching for the answer to this, and although I found similar examples to this issue, they did not seem to work for me. I am trying to have a task scheduled to kill skype when a user logs in so that people don't have to close out every time they log on. I have to do this by writing code rather than manually because it will be a script run to set up new computers. here is my code that writes the task:

please note that the commented lines are from solutions I have tried but failed to work the way I wanted it to

```
Option Explicit

Dim wShell, outFile, objFSO, ret

Set wShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
wShell.Run "N:\Internfolder\INCA_Scripts\SkypeKill.vbs"
'wShell.Run "cmd start ""N:\Internfolder\INCA_Scripts\Schedule_SkypeKill.bat"""
'wShell.Run "N:\Internfolder\INCA_Scripts\Schedule_SkypeKill.bat"
wShell.Run "SCHTASKS /create  /tn ""Schedule_Kill_Skype""  /tr ""N:\Internfolder\INCA_Scripts\SkypeKill.vbs"" /sc onlogon", 0   

'set wShell = Nothing
'WScript.sleep(15000)
WScript.echo "completed"
```

and here is the .vbs file for SkypeKill:

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim timer
timer = 0

Do
    'attempt to kill skype (lync.exe) 
    r = oShell.Run("taskkill /F /IM lync.exe",0, True)

    'if r = 0, then skyp was opened, then killed
    if r= 0 then
        WScript.echo "Skype was opened, but has been termiated. Hit 'Enter' to exit."
        WScript.quit

    'else, we wait until it is opened for 35 seconds, and kill it if it appears
    else
        WScript.sleep(3000)
        timer = timer + 3
        if timer = 35 Then Exit Do
    end if
Loop

WScript.echo "Skype kill has been attempted"
```

the last bit of important information is that when I schedule the task to run this script, it says that the system cannot find the file specified, however the SkypeKill.vbs file is in the specified location (N:\Internfolder\INCA_Scripts\SkypeKill.vbs), which is a bit odd.

So with this I have a couple questions. I am assuming that there is something wrong with how I am attempting to schedule the task, given that it will not show up in the task scheduler when i run the first block of code. but, neither code throws any errors. How can I get this to actually write into the task scheduler and kill skype once the user has logged in and started up? Does the fact that I am running on Windows 7 and Windows 10 matter when trying to complete this task? or is there an easier way to do this via code that I am overlooking. Please help soon! Thanks!

Comment: You seem to expect the `Run` method to raise an error when the external command fails. That is not the case. Use `rc = wShell.Run("schtasks ...", 0) : wsh.Echo rc` to see the exit code of the external command. Use `rc = wShell.Run("cmd /k schtasks ...", 1)` to see the output of the external command.

Comment: see answer below for my workaround to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, However I have resolved the issue simply by including the following code before the shell functions are executed:

`If WScript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", "c:\Users\admin\Documents\selfConfigure.vbs -1", "", runas", 1
End If`

this elevates my priveleges to access the drive/file paths I need to access, as I was receiving an "access denied" error in command prompt. the issue has been resolved and the task has been written to the scheduler.